# What's the difference between end and finish events in Node streams

Tags: node.js, stream

Node.js streams triggers both `end` and `finish` events. What's the difference between both?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

`end` and `finish` are the same event BUT on different types of Streams.

- `stream.Readable` fires ONLY `end` and NEVER `finish`
- `stream.Writable` fires ONLY `finish` and NEVER `end`

Source: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/stream.html

**Why the different naming of the same event?**

The only reason I could think of is because of duplex streams (`stream.Duplex`), which implement both `stream.Readable` and `stream.Writable` interfaces (https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_duplex) are readable and writable stream at the same time. To differentiate between end of reading and end of writing on the stream you must have a different event fired. SO, for Duplex streams `end` is end of reading and `finish` is end of writing.

Comment: And also a `Transform` stream has both `end` and `finish` events. Indeed it extends `Duplex`.

Comment: is this still valid in for the steams API after Node.js version 8?

Comment: @AlexanderMills What did the docs say (https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/stream.html)? Also, you can try a simple test case with for example fs.ReadStream and fs.WriteStream - https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_readstream. Feel free to contribute your findings.

Comment: `end` of data vs. `finished`  working makes sense.  A writable may have received all the data it is going to get, e.g. it received an `end` from upstream, but still be working.  (I'm not sure but guessing that for a transform `finished` always comes after `end`?)

Comment: @tiblu The docs (even 5.x) contain opposite information. "`finish` is fired after `end`". As your answer has 160 upvotes I think I'm missing something here. Please clarify!

Comment: @fishbone I don't state the exact event order in the original post? I would think the order is not guaranteed and depends on the exact streaming scenario at hand?

Comment: @tiblu I quoted this statement from the docs because that means they both fire (even for writable stream). In constrast your answer says either `finish` or `end` fires, depending on the stream type. That's the actual point of your answer and I can't find it in the docs.

Comment: @fishbone IF you refer to this https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_events_finish_and_end which states:
`The **finish** event is fired after **stream.end()** is called and all chunks have been processed by stream._transform(), **end** is fired after all data has been output which is after the callback in stream._flush() has been called.`. 
Its about Transform streams.
IF this is NOT what u are referring to, please add precise references (links).
IF you still think both are fired for writable, write test code to prove it. Share the code.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, that was the missing point. Unfortunately SO doesn't let me remove the down vote