# vinyl-fs (gulp file stream) not finishing .dest write before firing callback or promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, promise, node.js-stream

Frustratingly trying to get a vinyl-fs (gulpfs) stream to finish writing ALL the .dest files before launching code to upload a copy of the destination folder to an S3 bucket.  That copy operation keeps missing a directory that the stream has yet to write.

**The issue is how vinly-fs plays with callbacks/promises (does it?).**

I've put together some testing code to experiment but when that code is run the promise is resolved immediately (after the writes start?) even though I FORCED the stream to wait for 5 seconds after the .dest command before firing the promise resolve.  My resolve function currently fires and then 5 seconds later I'm back to my prompt.  Totally stuck on this.  I don't want to live without vinyl-fs but it just doesn't seem to play well no matter what I try and I need this to work as a sequence (write ALL files out before uploading them).

Below is my testing code. I set this up so you can easily put dump the code into a file, set some source directory and try for yourself.  I looked at gulpjs issues and on stackoverflow and some others are having the same problem but I have seen no definitive answer/solution.

test.js

```
var source = './builds/**/*.*';

var p = foo(source);

p.then( bar, oopsBar );

//
// vinyl-fs based module task
//
function foo(src) {

  var fs = require('vinyl-fs');
  var wait = require('gulp-wait')

  done = new Promise( function(resolve,reject){
      fs.src(src)
        .pipe(fs.dest('./temp'))
        .pipe(wait(5000))
        .on('finish',resolve());

    });
    // return a promise
    return done;
}

function bar() {
    console.log('Now uploading to S3 bucket');
}

function oopsBar() {
    console.log('Something went wrong');
}
```

BTW you might be wondering why I just don't use gulp.task and return the promise and fire my upload as a separate gulp task.  I currently minimize my gulp.tasks to cli started tasks.  Eventually like running this code just use wow "node test" instead and remove the global gulp dependency and gulpfile.js all together.  Vinyl-fs is a great module!, but I've decided it's best not to buy into Gulp/Grunt/Brunch/Jake thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you wanted

```
.on('finish', resolve)
```

instead of calling `resolve()` right away. Also, readable streams don't emit a [`finish` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish), they emit an [`end` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end), so you 'd have to use

```
.on('end', resolve)
```

Comment: try it.  If you do that the resolve function "bar" is never called.  After 5 seconds it comes back to prompt.

Comment: @DKebler: that only suggests that `finish` is never fired. Not that immediately resolving the promise would be the way to go.

Comment: Yes @Bergi you are right.  So I tried 'end'  `.on('end', resolve)`  bingo it works!  So can you or someone else explain this difference between end and finish? So if you change your post to 'end' I'll up vote and make it the answer.

Comment: @DKebler: I just did edit :-) see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/28334610/1048572