# process.stdin - difference between end and finish events

Tags: node.js, stdin, stdio, node-streams

When it comes to `process.stdin`, does anybody know the difference between the `end` and `finish` events?

```
   process.stdin.resume()
    .once('end', function(){
      log.info('stdin has ended.');
    })
    .once('finish', function(){
      log.info('stdin has finished.');  
    });
```

looks like 'finished' event is called first, 'end' event is fired afterwards. What does these events signify more exactly?

Is `process.stdin` a *duplex* stream since it fires both events?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334610/whats-the-difference-between-end-and-finish-events-in-node-streams

Comment: huh, so is `process.stdin` a duplex stream since it fires both events?

Comment: seems like according to the link as it fires both end and finished